# C++ thread safe hash map

Tags: c++, collections, stl, hashmap, thread-safety

I am looking for thread safe implementation of hash/unordered map allows simultaneous insert/delete.

I am aware of concurrent_hash_map in TBB but it's very slow compared to other counterparts. Wrapping std maps into locks is not an option, looking for an implementation which was designed with thread safely and speed as criteria. I understand it may not be as fast as other non thread safe implementation but should not be as slow as concurrent_hash_map

Thanks in advance for your inputs

Comment: Asking questions for library suggestions are considered off topic on this site, so your question will probably get closed.

Comment: I suspect that you will not find what you need, because in such a case thread safety and performance are practically mutually exclusive (for a complex data structure like this). Of course performance is relative to your needs...

Comment: look at http://www.stdthread.co.uk/prodoc/headers/concurrent_map.html (not open source, though)